# In an array with null spaces, how can consolidate all of the non null values together?

Tags: java, arrays, consolidation

Hey so I have this homework assignment and I'm having issues with one of the methods. I would like hints and not actual answers/code.

So I have a class called HorseBarn that messes with an array of horses(horse being the type). My problem is I'm having troubles with the consolidate method.

What the array would look like before consolidate:
a,b,c,d are horses

|a|null|b|null|c|d|

What the array would look like after consolidate:

|a|b|c|d|null|null|

So my logic would be to make a nested for loop. The first loop would search for a null value, once the first loop finds the null value, the second loop would look for a horse and then swap with it. Then the second loop would end and go back to the first loop. So here is what I have right now and it doesn't work(it just terminates). Is my logic wrong or is it my syntax that's causing the problems?

```
public void consolidate()
{
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < spaces.length;i++)
    {
        if( spaces[i] == null)
        {
            for(j = i; j < spaces.length && spaces[j] == null; j++)
            {

            }
            spaces[i] = spaces[j];
            spaces[j] = null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your code seems OK at a first glance, how can you tell it's not working?

Comment: Why is the inner `for` loop empty? Are the statements after it intended to be in the body of the loop?

Comment: @DavidConrad , think of it a "next-non-null" setter (it looks for the next "non-null" and sets it there. :)

Comment: @Totoro , but isn't that what the if statement is doing?

Comment: @DavidConrad, there is a problem of putting objects in the last cell of the array, but the logic of the empty loop is ok. it's clearer to just terminate it with no curly-braces.

Comment: @ReutSharabani , I have a test file that tells me if the the method worked or not.

Comment: can you tell us what the array looks like before and after the method? do **you** know? It's a different level of familiarity with the code to say "it's not working", and "I know how it's not working"

Comment: -- Barn 2 (before consolidate) --
[0]: Trigger, 1340lbs.
[1]: null
[2]: Silver, 1210lbs.
[3]: null
[4]: null
[5]: Patches, 1350lbs.
[6]: Duke, 1410lbs.

 -- Barn 2 (after consolidate) --
[0]: Trigger, 1340lbs.
[1]: Silver, 1210lbs.
[2]: Patches, 1350lbs.
[3]: Duke, 1410lbs.
[4]: null
[5]: null
[6]: null

Comment: That is what it should look like, the output just returns 7 after consolidate is called.

Comment: isn't that exactly what the code should do?

Comment: what does your code do to the array? what does `consolidate`, that you've written, do to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for starters, this should give an index out of bounds exception if the last non-null is found and there still are elements remaining:

ex: `horses = | a | null | null | null |`

for `i = 1`, since horses[1] -> horses[3] are empty, j first gets set to 1 then ends with j = 4 (because of the termination condition `j < horses.length()`)

You would then try to swap horses[1] with horses[4], which throws the array index out of bounds

Comment: better yet - factor it out to a `swap(arr, i, j)` function :-)

Comment: @ReutSharabani how does that help against index out of bounds?

Comment: A `swap` method should conceptually check against minimal (negative) and maximal values, so the bug would surface easily.

This code's logic doesn't reflect well from it so it's harder to spot bugs like the one mentioned.

Comment: Oh, I thought you just wanted him to wrap those two lines into `swap(arr, i, j)`

Comment: This function does more than one thing when it really doesn't have to - perfect place for errors :)

Answer (score 0):

In the inner for loop, just find the position of next non null value and break it there.
Then swap it with your null.
A better time efficient code.